# How to get a list from another list in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I wanna ask some thing
Let's say I have list of employee, and each employee contains list of approvals.

And it looks like this

```
"employeeList": [
{
    "id": 1,
    "employee_name": "Johny Doe",
    "approval": [
        {
            "title": "Manager 1",
            "approved": true
        },
        {
            "title": "Manager 2",
            "approved": true
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "employee_name": "Jane Doe",
    "approval": [
        {
            "title": "Manager 1",
            "approved": true
        },
        {
            "title": "Manager 2",
            "approved": false
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "employee_name": "Falcon X",
    "approval": [
        {
            "title": "Manager 1",
            "approved": true
        },
        {
            "title": "Manager 2",
            "approved": true
        }
    ]
}]
```

the thing is I wanna show list which only approved by Manager 1 and Manager 2,
this is what it looks like

```
"employeeList": [
{
    "id": 1,
    "employee_name": "Johny Doe",
    "approval": [
        {
            "title": "Manager 1",
            "approved": true
        },
        {
            "title": "Manager 2",
            "approved": true
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "employee_name": "Falcon X",
    "approval": [
        {
            "title": "Manager 1",
            "approved": true
        },
        {
            "title": "Manager 2",
            "approved": true
        }
    ]
}]
```

How to achieve this is in Java ?
Can I have suggestion ?
Any suggestion would be helped

Thanks in advance

Comment: Iterate the list and simply save the desired items to a new list. What have you tried so far? How are you representing this data in code? And what issues are you facing that stop you from doing this?

Comment: Please share any code you have tried, any attempt (even if it isn't working). Also, this might be useful to read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
record Approval(String title, boolean approved) {}
record Employee(int id, String employee_name, List<Approval> approval) {}

List<Employee> employees = List.of(
    new Employee(1, "Johny Doe",
        List.of(new Approval("Manager 1", true), new Approval("Manager 2", true))),
    new Employee(2, "Jane Doe",
        List.of(new Approval("Manager 1", true), new Approval("Manager 2", false))),
    new Employee(3, "Falcon X",
        List.of(new Approval("Manager 1", true), new Approval("Manager 2", true))));

Approval m1 = new Approval("Manager 1", true),
         m2 = new Approval("Manager 2", true);

List<Employee> result = employees.stream()
    .filter(e -> e.approval.contains(m1) && e.approval.contains(m2))
    .toList();

for (Employee e : result)
    System.out.println(e);
```

output:

```
Employee[id=1, employee_name=Johny Doe, approval=[Approval[title=Manager 1, approved=true], Approval[title=Manager 2, approved=true]]]
Employee[id=3, employee_name=Falcon X, approval=[Approval[title=Manager 1, approved=true], Approval[title=Manager 2, approved=true]]]
```

If you use `class` instead of `record`, you need to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` appropriately.